# Creating Object-Oriented Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC and Razor.

Using Razor, I am able to create helpers that print HTML code.  However, I would like to take an object oriented approach, where my helpers have methods to add code.

However, if I just use C# to return HTML, then I am writing HTML in a string, which is difficult to maintain. Is there some best-practice that allows me to combine the best of both worlds?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you have some classes to help you.

One. [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and UrlHelper. HtmlHelper can generate code for you, for example:

> HtmlHelper.TextBox()

Two. [TagBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). TagBuilder enables you to write more custom elements.

> TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
>      builder.GenerateId(id);
>      builder.MergeAttribute("type", "submit");
>      builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
>
> string html = builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

Comment: Any luck? Do you need more help?